# Iterating over a mongodb collection doesn't return all objects

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a cron job that runs a very simple script over a mongo database:

```
import pymongo
db=pymongo.Connection().dbase
ids=[]
for obj in db.coll.find(): ids.append(obj['_id'])
# log len(ids), db.coll.count()
```

In logs db.coll.count() is always 651 and len(ids) is mostly 651 too, but sometimes it is 5,85,71 or other random numbers below 651. Can anybody explain why this discrepancy happens and how to prevent it please?

The environment is: a standalone server with multiple clients that may update objects in the collection concurrently.

Comment: Make sure you use the [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) class for connecting to MongoDB

Comment: I use pymongo 2.2, it seems there is no MongoClient class in this version...

Comment: unable to reproduce the problem; I ran the test 1000 times - using pymongo 2.5

Comment: Are you regenerating the data in the collection? because there is a short but certain time between you run the db.coll.find() and db.coll.count() commands. Are you sure the number of the documents are not change through delete or insert operations in between?